# why is there LG_VHDL in gwan.h?

Tags: scripting, programming-languages, vhdl, g-wan

In the gwan.h header i see there is LG_VHDL.
VHDL is, as far as i know, mostly for FPGA programming.

Could you please tell me more why, what, how there is a something related to vhdl here ?
I can't find anything about gwan and vhdl anywhere.

vhdl is a description language, you describe how the hardware is supposed to works and there is an insanely complex compiler that make it real. How could it be possible to describe a cgi in vhdl ?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question.

When you relate the two products of TrustLeap: `G-WAN` and its `Crypto` technology, it may make sense to serve the needs of tiny (but well-financed) communities.

`VHDL` qualifies for both criterias.

The list you are referring to includes the following programming languages:

```
enum
{
   LG_ADA,
   LG_ASM,
   LG_BASIC,
   LG_C,
   LG_COBOL,
   LG_CPP,
   LG_CS,
   LG_D,
   LG_FORTRAN,
   LG_GO,
   LG_JAVA,
   LG_JS,
   LG_LUA,
   LG_MERCURY,
   LG_MODULA,
   LG_OBJC,
   LG_OBJCPP,
   LG_PASCAL,
   LG_PERL,
   LG_PHP,
   LG_PLI,
   LG_PYTHON,
   LG_RUBY,
   LG_SCALA,
   LG_SCHEME,
   LG_VHDL
};
```

As you can see, some of those programming languages are not (yet) implemented in the public release of G-WAN (so far "only" 16 of them are made available, and a couple should follow by the end of the year).

But we also make *custom* versions of G-WAN for sophisticated users whos ask us to implement the specific features they need.

Adding support for more programming languages in G-WAN is not done to be encyclopedic, nor in an attempt to make any (weird) Guinness World record.

The main point pursued by G-WAN is to be *useful to our users*. They define what their needs are, and we are delighted to please.

Would someone ask for a programming language that is not in this list to be supported, and pay for it to be implemented (doing so takes time and skills), who are we to disagree?

G-WAN has been made to offer users the choice, in an environment where development tools fight to impose a monoculture (whether it is all-Java or all-C#, or all PHP, etc.).

As a software engineer for a few decades, I can only think about it like a progress.

Comment: Ok thank you. This mean that if i pay enough i could have a version of g-wan which could use the help of an FPGA coprocessor for most cpu intensive task or custom I/O. correct ?

Comment: If you pay for the time and skills needed for custom developments you want to be made then you will get any feature you need, including the support by G-WAN of new programming languages, without regard to how exotic their use may look like: https://github.com/trending?l=vhdl